# Ballerina: incompatible dependencies after pulling new distribution

Tags: ballerina

I have a Ballerina project which compiles successfully using the slalpha2 distribution. After pulling slalpha3, I get this message when compiling:

> error: compilation failed: Two incompatible versions exist in the dependency graph: ballerina/random versions: 0.10.0-alpha5, 0.10.0-alpha4

If I set my distribution back to slalpha2, everything is fine again.

I gather that it's trying to get the versions of ballerina/random for both distributions when I try to compile against slalpha3. That might be because I'm using a module from Ballerina Central which depends on ballerina/random.

Does that intermediate module need to be recompiled against slalpha3?

Is there some way to tell Ballerina to only use one version or the other of ballerina/random?

Comment: What is the package in Ballerina central that you are using in your code?

Comment: 'bidalaka/random`.